# Phone doesn't recognize xinput controller

Tags: game-controllers

So i bought this controller that can switch between xinput and dinput and it came with a usb otg cable so i thought "Hey why don't i try to connect it to my phone" so i did. At first i was a bit disappointed cause it didn't work, but after a while i tried switching to dinput and it worked. My PC recognizes it as a xinput controller and the games work perfectly, so the controller isn't the problem.

Additional details: 
Huawei P9 lite
Android 7.0

Pls halp thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XInput is a part of the DirectX 9 (and up), originally made for Xbox 360. It is rarely supported by Android devices.

DInput is an acronym for **D**irect**Input**, part of DirectX 8.1 and lower, originally made for Windows, and embedded. Since it's part of Windows' (or PC's) standard control API, most Android devices supports it natively.

That's why your controller works in DInput mode but not XInput.

Comment: Thanks, but the interwebs said that you can connect an xbox controller to almost any android device and it works. And i tried my friends xbox controller yesterday and the same happened- the lights were on but it doesn't recognize it. Anyways, i would like to know if i can get this to work somehow because all of the mobile games support only xinput.

Comment: I recommend you get another controller. I've never seen someone successfully used an Xbox Ctrler on Android.

Comment: Ok I'll close this question because i came up with a conclusion: my phone doesn't support wired xinput controller, but luckily it supports dinput. By the way my friend gave me his 8bitdo nes30 pro controller wich is a bluetooth xinput controller and it works great so everything is fine now. Thanks again!